# how to translate and scale the image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

My image looks like this:

The given imrgb = 320*512*3 double; color_map = 64*3 double; after using

```
[X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb, color_map);
```

I get X = 320*512 uint8. The image is too big for the further processing. My 
question is how to translate and scale the image to a standard size of 32*32 pixels without losing the important information ( I mean the non-black part of the image are all important information)?

Comment: Huh?  Do you want to resize the entire image down to 32 x 32, or do you want to resize each patch inside the image down to 32 x 32?  Resizing down to a smaller size will always lose information.

Comment: @rayryeng, I want to use this image do classification. I do not know which choice is better? Can you tell me separately for 1) resize the entire image down to 32*32; 2) resize each patch inside the image down to 32*32? And another question, Can you tell me how to and is it possible to resize the image to 32*32 by only losing the information of the black part of the image and save the information of the  40 patches in the image?

Comment: Resizing will always lose information because you're essentially discarding pixels to compute the resized result.  I don't quite understand what you mean by "saving" information when that isn't possible.

Comment: @rayryeng , I want to  know  separately how to 1) resize the entire image down to 32*32; and 2) resize each patch inside the image down to 32*32? Please teach me!

Comment: I wouldn't advise that you do the first option.  If you resize the entire image down to 32 x 32, your 40 brain images will be a few pixels large per brain. If you want to do the second option, that seems more plausible.  Can you tell me if each patch in the brain image is equal size?  That is, are all brain images inside the larger image the same size?  Also, when you resize the images, depending on which interpolation scheme you use, you may be introducing new colours that were not part of the original colour map. Is that something you can tolerate? Minor comment: 320 x 512 is not big at all.

Comment: @rayryeng,each patch in the brain image is not equal size. Because I have 1210 such 320*512 images. I want to put them into block and combine to a larger image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution where I make each brain tile a `32x32` image. The comments explain the code. But the basic idea is...

using block proc

1. to split the large image into a 5x8 grid, because it has 5 rows of brains and 8 columns of brains. I call each of these images a tile
2. Resize each tile to 32x32

using mat2cell

3. split the new small tiles into individual images and display them

Here is the code

```erlang
im = rgb2gray(imrgb);

max_rows = 32;
max_cols = 32;

%I assume every picture has 40 brains, 5 rows and 8 columns
rows_brains = 5;
cols_brains = 8;
[m n] = size(im);

%define the resize function to take the 'block_struct' image and resize
%it to max_rows x max_cols
fun = @(block_struct) imresize(block_struct.data,[max_rows max_cols]);

%blockproc will split the image into tiles. Each tile should hold one brain
%image. Then we resize that tile to a 32x32 tile using the resize function
%we defined earlier
I2 = blockproc(im,[m/rows_brains n/cols_brains],fun);

%split the image with small tiles into individual pictures
%each cell of indiv_brains will contain a 32x32 image of only one brain
indiv_brains = mat2cell(I2,max_rows*ones(1,rows_brains),max_cols*ones(1,cols_brains));

%displays all the brains
figure(1);

for ii=1:1:rows_brains
    for jj=1:1:cols_brains
        subplot(rows_brains, cols_brains, (ii-1)*cols_brains + jj);
        imshow(indiv_brains{ii,jj});
    end
end
```

and the result, each of these individual images is 32x32

[image]

Comment: I run your code. There is error , what is "im " in your code?

Comment: `im = rgb2gray(imrgb);`

Comment: thanks for that rayryeng I've edited the code. Sorry I left it out @Angelababy